# can i compare different rows in data extension by ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, data

i have this kind of data in a data extension:

DesktopType1 (column-Name) Hard Drive 250 (column-Spec)

DesktopType1 (column-Name) RAM 4GB (column-Spec)

DesktopType1 (column-Name) 1080p (column-Spec)

DesktopType2 (column-Name) Hard Drive 150 (column-Spec)

DesktopType2 (column-Name) Wifi (column-Spec)

Since i can have multiple rows for each product depending on the spec. Can i compare two or more products and display the difference in email body by ampscript?

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of the desired output.

Comment: Could you also please add a bit more clarity around the content of the input? A screenshot might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your values would need to be a number (i.e. 250 instead of Hard Drive 250GB, and 4 instead of RAM 4 GB, etc). You could use math functions after you LookupRows to make your comparisons.